# Why `onActivityResult()` is returning null data when recording an audio?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, onactivityresult, android-audiorecord

I'm using [this](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder) library in my app for recording audio.

Here's my code:

```
String filePath;

recordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) +
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/recorded_audio.wav";
            int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            AndroidAudioRecorder.with(MainActivity.this)
                    // Required
                    .setFilePath(filePath)
                    .setColor(color)
                    .setRequestCode(RECORD_PRODUCT_DAMAGE)

                    // Optional
                    .setSource(AudioSource.MIC)
                    .setChannel(AudioChannel.STEREO)
                    .setSampleRate(AudioSampleRate.HZ_48000)
                    .setAutoStart(true)
                    .setKeepDisplayOn(true)

                    // Start recording
                    .record();
        }
    }
});
```

Here's code in `onActivityResult()`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECORD_PRODUCT_DAMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Great! User has recorded and saved the audio file
                Toast.makeText(this, "Audio recorded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (data == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Data is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                playRecordedAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Uri uriPath = null;
                    uriPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
                    try{
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), uriPath);
                        mp.start();
                    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
                        // handle NullPointerException
                    }
                }
            });

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Oops! User has canceled the recording
                Toast.makeText(this, "Audio was not recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Here, the `Toast` 'Data is null' is getting shown.

Why is this happening? Why am I unable to get the recorded audio file as the `data` here?

Please let me know.

Comment: Look through the source, where [the result](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/cafe/adriel/androidaudiorecorder/AudioRecorderActivity.java#L165) [is set](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/cafe/adriel/androidaudiorecorder/AudioRecorderActivity.java#L211). All it returns is the result code. Presumably it's up to you to load the audio file, since you have the file path already (`setFilePath(filePath)`).

Comment: @MikeM. I want this recorded audio to be played on the click of a button. How can I?

Comment: Do something like is shown with `MediaPlayer` in [this answer on your last question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44038639), except you wouldn't need the `getPathForAudio()` method, since you've already got the `filePath`.